# Independence test for two small, exhaustive, categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, simulation, independence, small-sample

I've got a categorical variable $var$ and a binary variable $critere$, from a pretty small (n = 300) but exhaustive dataset (i.e., the dataset contains the whole population that I want to study).

I want to assert whether $var$ and $critere$ are independent, but because of the exhaustivity problem I don't want to use an asymptotic test such as the chi-square.

So I turn to simulation (R code beneath). Let's say I have $n$ observations, of which $p$ have $critere$ equal to 1. For some large number of iterations (e.g. 10,000), I sample $p$ elements in $var$ without replacement, and for each of those iterations I compute the [total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between the sample I drew and the remaining $(n-p)$ observations of $var$ (the ones I did not draw).

This yields a simulated distribution of distances, which corresponds to the distribution of distances one would have if $critere$ was drawn at random from a $Bernoulli\left(\frac{p}{n}\right)$, and from there I compute the p-value of the observed distance.

Is this reasoning correct? Would I be better off just using Fisher's exact test?

```
simVarDist <- function(var, critere, n= 1e4) { 
  var <- as.factor(var)
  length.var <- length(var)
  sum.critere <- sum(critere)
  simu <- replicate(1e4, sample(length.var, sum.critere), 
                    simplify= FALSE)
  simu.dist <- sapply(simu, function (x) max(abs(table(var[x]) /  
                sum.critere - table(var[-x]) / (length.var - 
                sum.critere))))
  list(simu.distance.quant95= quantile(simu.dist, .95), 
    empir.distance= max(abs(table(var[critere]) / sum.critere - 
    table(var[-critere]) / (length.var - sum.critere))), 
       p.value= mean(simu.dist > max(abs(table(var[critere]) / 
       sum.critere - table(var[-critere]) / (length.var - 
       sum.critere)))))
}
```

Comment: What is the point of simulation when you have the entire population? All you would really need to do in that case is apply the definition of independence, which is extremely easy to check. Your resorting to this method suggests you aren't really thinking of your data as a population (which is an extremely rare circumstance), but rather as a sample of something.

Comment: But just applying the definition of independence (comparing the joint distribution to the product of marginals) would practically never give independence (in the sense of exact equality). The reason why I use simulation is to answer the question "how different is this observed distance from the case where the binary variable would be randomly drawn".

Comment: That's not a question about a population, is it?  It seems to be about a random process.  If your question truly is about the entire population, then "practically never" is a meaningless criterion: either these variables are independent or they are not, period.

Comment: So for two variables x and y in (0,1), with frequencies F(x=0, y=0)= 14, F(x=0, y=1)= 16, F(x=1, y=0)= 16, F(x=1, y=1)= 14, would you say x and y are independent?

Comment: Just apply [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_random_variables).

Comment: I take that as a yes, of course the definition says x and y are not independent in this case. But surely the difference in distributions does not seem very "significant"...

Comment: You're talking about significance in the everyday sense ("practical significance"), not statistical significance there, since it's certainly significant in the statistical sense. Practical significance is generally about whether an effect is large enough to matter in some way, which isn't a statistical question, but comes from subject matter understanding, what you're using it for, plus your own preferences and those of your audience (Is a piece of string 'big'? If you're attaching notes to pigeon's legs, three inches might be 'big' )